# How would you /effect someone with chainmail boots with only 1 command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a Hide and Seek map on one of my friends realms, and I want to make certain boots give different effects (such as diamond boots give speed).  I have something with two command blocks right here:

1. `/testfor @a{[team=Hider]Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:chainmail_boots"}]} |`

Then a comparator to the next.

2. `/effect minecraft:resistance 1 3 true |`

But that only effects the nearest player to the command blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not near a computer but a from what I remember you are looking for `/execute [selector] x y z [command]` So your command would be:

```
/execute @a{[team=Hider]Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:chainmail_boots"}]} ~ ~ ~ effect minecraft:resistance 1 3`
```